# How to automate loading multiple files into numpy arrays using a simple "for" loop?

Tags: python, numpy

I usually load my data, that -in most cases- consists of only two columns using np.loadtxt cammand as follows:

```
x0, y0 = np.loadtxt('file_0.txt', delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
x1, y1 = np.loadtxt('file_1.txt', delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
.
.
xn, yn = np.loadtxt('file_n.txt', delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
```

then plot each pair on its own, which is not ideal!

I want to make a simple "for" loop that goes for all text files in the same directory, load the files and plot them on the same figure.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# A list of all file names that end with .txt
myfiles = [myfile for myfile in os.listdir() if myfile.endswith(".txt")]

# Create a new figure
plt.figure()

# iterate over the file names
for myfile in myfiles:
   # load the x, y
   x, y = np.loadtxt(myfile, delimiter='\t', unpack=True)

   # plot the values
   plt.plot(x, y)

# show the figure after iterating over all files and plotting.
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Load all the files in a dictionary using:

```
d = {}
for i in range(n):
    d[i] = np.loadtxt('file_' + str(i) + '.txt', delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
```

Now, to access `k`th file, use `d[k]` or:

```
xk, yk = d[k]
```

Since, you have not mentioned about the data in the files and the plot you want to create, it's hard to tell what to do. But for plotting, you can refer [Mttplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) or [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) libraries.

Comment: Thanks. But, how to load files of arbitrary names?!

Comment: [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53503041/13720565)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `glob` to get all the files -

```
from glob import glob
import numpy as np
import os

res = []

file_path = "YOUR PATH"
file_pattern = "file_*.txt"

files_list = glob(os.path.join(file_path,file_pattern))

for f in files_list:
    print(f'----- Loading {f} -----')
    x, y = np.loadtxt(f, delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
    res += [(x,y)]
```

`res` will contain your file contents at each index value corresponding to `f`